# Are there tax implications of refund of overpayment from HSA?

Tags: taxes, health-insurance, hsa

possibly related: [How do I correct an HSA distribution when I was refunded by a health provider?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/47303/35619), [Can I get a rebate after using my HSA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/15866/35619) (But I don't really understand the topic and those questions well enough to know.)

---

#### The Story:

I have an HSA (through work) in addition to my job-provided health insurance plan. Some months ago I received a bill from *PROVIDER* and paid *DOLLARS* out of my HSA. My payment and a second notice from *PROVIDER* crossed paths in the mail. Not really being on  top of my game, when I received second notice from *PROVIDER* I paid it with *DOLLARS* out of my HSA.

Recently I received a refund check in the amount of *DOLLARS* from *PROVIDER*. I deposited *DOLLARS* into my traditional checking account.

So *DOLLARS* flowed out of my HSA, was refunded to me by *PROVIDER*, and is now in my bank account.

#### The Questions:

1. Can I put *DOLLARS* back into m HSA somehow? If I can, do I need to file anything to identify the erroneous payout from the HSA with my later "repayment" to the HSA?
2. If I can't put *DOLLARS* back into the HSA, how do I pay the proper taxes on that money? It went to my HSA pre-tax....

#### [Background Info](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2218/35619):

- The originating event, two paments by me, and refund have all occured within calendar year 2015.
- I still have access to the HSA. Nothing about my insurance or HSA has changed this year or will change whenwe hit calendar year 2016. Except the cost of my premiums, of course. (Ohh... you almost got me there, *INSURER*.)

Comment: There is no need to panic; these things happen all the time. Just talk to your HSA custodian (bank) and tell them you need to make a mistaken distribution repayment. They might have a form you need to fill out when you give back the money. It is easiest if you do it before the end of the year. For more details, see the duplicate question.