# Rebates and FSA's

Tags: united-states, rebate, fsa

We signed up for an FSA this year, but usually pay cash for D's prescription and get the rebate. It's a significant amount of money. It takes the copay from $160 to $25. I'm just so used to submitting the rebates, that I didn't even think about it when D paid with the FSA card. So, I submitted it.

- Is there a way to put the money back on the FSA card?
- What will happen if they find out?
- Why can't you do a rebate WITH the FSA card?

  It would significantly reduce our copay. I won't do it again, now that I know, but I'd rather figure out the cash and get the rebate than lose the full $160 off my FSA card. It just doesn't make a lot of sense to me that they prevent you from getting the best price.

Comment: Who's giving you the rebate? Why can you only get the rebate if paying cash? Sounds fishy, such a significant discount for cash payments can be a sign of tax evasion on the other end.

Answer (score 2):

While this question [Can I get a rebate after using my HSA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15866/can-i-get-a-rebate-after-using-my-hsa) mentions Health savings account the answer is still applicable.

Go to the website for the plan administrator. They will either have a form to put the money back into the account, or they will have a contact number. In the past when I had an FSA I did this.

In one case I remember the doctor told us the bill would be X, but when they submitted the claim to the insurance the final bill was less than X so the doctor's office sent us the extra back. I was able to return the money back to the FSA administrator following their procedure.

Your situation is not unusual, accidental transactions happen all the time.